# Ignore signal sent to my own process group

Tags: ruby, unix, signals

I'm writing a wrapper for a set of child processes, which I want to respond to some signals and propagate them to children. So for example if the wrapper receives `QUIT`, it should send `QUIT` to all the children (not only direct children but all processes spawned).

So I'm using `setsid` and then trapping the signals I want to handle with a code that just issues `kill(sig, 0)`. When I do that, the wrapper also gets the signal again (being the session leader and inside the process group) and and endless loop ensues.

I was thinking of setting some sort of flag (`already_handled_sig_X`) and consulting it before calling `kill`, but (a) it looks clunky and (b) when do I remove the flag?

BTW: the implementation language is Ruby, so if you want to put examples and feel like writing them in Ruby I'd appreciate it, otherwise - don't bother, I can handle C.

Here's my current (naive) implementation:

```
def run_stuff(cmd)
  fork do
    Process.setsid
    trap(:QUIT) { Process.kill(:QUIT, 0) }
    trap(:TERM) { Process.kill(:TERM, 0) }
    IO.popen(cmd) do |io|
      while line = io.gets
        $log.warn line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I just set a flag to ignore additional signals. The sample code above should be modified thus:

```
def run_stuff(cmd)
  fork do
    Process.setsid
    shuttingdown = false
    trap(:QUIT) do
      next if shuttingdown
      shuttingdown = true
      Process.kill(:QUIT, 0)
    end
    trap(:TERM) do
      next if shuttingdown
      shuttingdown = true
      Process.kill(:TERM, 0)
    end
    IO.popen(cmd) do |io|
      while line = io.gets
        $log.warn line
      end
    end
  end
end
```